# Using a class as a parameter with another class. (C++)

Tags: c++, function, inheritance

I'm trying to make make a small section of code, which will check two classes together. It was set as university work, but I'm struggling to make this final function work as I want it too.

I'm unsure mostly on how to get the Monster::chase(class Hero) function to be allowed access too the Hero variables I need to check.

I know it's probably something simple I've overlook, or just been blind too, but any help would be much appreciated.

---

```
//Monster.cpp

#include "Creature.h"
#include "Monster.h"
#include "Hero.h"

Monster::Monster() : Creature(m_name, m_xpos, m_ypos)
{
}

void Monster::chase(class Hero)
{
    if(Monster::m_xpos < Hero::m_xpos) //Error: a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object
    {
        Monster::right();
    }

    if(Monster::m_xpos > ___?___)
    {
        Creature::left();
    }

    if(Monster::m_ypos < ___?___)
    {
        Creature::down();
    }

    if(Monster::m_ypos >___?___)
    {
        Creature::up();
    }
}

bool Monster::eaten(class Hero)
{

    if((Monster::m_xpos == ___?___)&&(Monster::m_ypos == ___?___))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

```
//monster.h

#pragma once
#include "Creature.h"

class Monster : public Creature
{
public:
    Monster();
    void chase(class Hero);
    bool eaten(class Hero);
};
```

---

```
#include "Creature.h"

Creature::Creature(string name, int xpos, int ypos)
{
    m_xpos = xpos;
    m_ypos = ypos;
    m_name = name;
}

void Creature::Display(void)
{
    cout << m_name << endl;
    cout << m_xpos << endl;
    cout << m_ypos << endl;
}

void Creature::left(void)
{
    m_xpos = m_xpos+1;
}

void Creature::right(void)
{
    m_xpos = m_xpos-1;
}

void Creature::up(void)
{
    m_ypos = m_ypos-1;
}

void Creature::down(void)
{
    m_ypos = m_ypos+1;
}

void Creature::setX(int x)
{
    m_xpos = x;
}

void Creature::setY(int y)
{
    m_ypos = y;
}

int Creature::getX(void)
{
    return m_xpos;
}

int Creature::getY(void)
{
    return m_ypos;
}
```

---

---

Ended up using this as the solution!

Thanks everyone who suggested answers!

What a fantastic community!

```
void Monster::chase(Hero hero)
{
    if(getX() < hero.getX())
    {
        right();
    }
```

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your first question on StackOverflow. Welcome! Note that `(Hero hero)`, creates a *copy* of your `Hero` object. This may not be what you want to do.

Comment: It seems to have solved the problem somewhat, now onto the next problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably meant to do something like:

```
void Monster::chase(Hero const& hero)
{
    if (getX() < hero.getX())
    {
        right();
    }
// [...]
```

...where you pass in a const-reference to an instance of the `Hero` `class` and call it `hero`.

You'll need to update the *declaration* in the header, too:

```
 void chase(Hero const& hero);
```

You can then invoke member functions on the `hero` instance using the `.` syntax.

Calling methods on the current object (`*this`) can be done as simply as `getX()` and `right()`.